# how to use Pi3d to draw an array

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, raspberry-pi, draw

I have an array containing x,y and z values like this:

```
-130.000000 735.000000 1.733333 
-128.000000 735.000000 1.706667 
-126.000000 735.000000 1.680000 
-124.000000 735.000000 1.653333 
-130.000000 736.000000 1.733333 
-128.000000 736.000000 1.706667 
-126.000000 736.000000 1.680000 
-124.000000 736.000000 1.653333 
-122.000000 736.000000 1.626667 
.......
```

i have searched on how to draw the array but i wasn't lucky to find out that

so how could i draw this array using Pi3d library ?
to get a result something like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ7dQ.png)

this is the [link](https://github.com/tipam/pi3d) of the library on GitHub

note: i am using Raspberry pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've obviously got somewhere to produce the image, it would be useful to see what you had done to get as far as you have. Could you post your code or a link to it?

In pi3d you have to pass at least two arrays to the Buffer class constructor. The minimum is an array of vertices, as per your post, along with an array defining the triangular faces. (You can also pass an array of normal vectors for each vertex and an array of texture coordinates). So for a square:

```
pts = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
faces = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3]]
shape = pi3d.Shape(...) # arguments as per docs
shape.buf[0] = pi3d.Buffer(shape=shape, pts=pts, texcoords=[], faces=faces)
```

You may be able to learn a bit more of how the system works by reading some of this http://paddywwoof.github.io/pi3d_book/_build/html/GPUexplain.html

EDIT I've just looked at your other three questions on stackoverflow and maybe you want to draw the vertices as points or as a line rather than a surface? If this is the case then you can create the Shape using

```
shape = pi3d.Lines(vertices=pts)
```

Again there are various arguments you can pass to control the way the line is drawn, see the docs.

EDIT 2, On reading your question more carefully I see that you haven't managed to do anything with pi3d and want help starting. You need to read the documentation and look through the demonstration programs; but this is the kind of thing you need to do to get a picture like the one you posted:

```
import pi3d
import math

DISPLAY = pi3d.Display.create(x=100, y=100, w=600, h=600)
CAMERA = pi3d.Camera()
shader = pi3d.Shader("mat_flat")

verts = [[-130.000000, 735.000000, 1.733333],
          [-128.000000, 735.000000, 1.706667], 
          [-126.000000, 735.000000, 1.680000], 
          [-124.000000, 735.000000, 1.653333], 
          [-130.000000, 736.000000, 1.733333], 
          [-128.000000, 736.000000, 1.706667], 
          [-126.000000, 736.000000, 1.680000], 
          [-124.000000, 736.000000, 1.653333], 
          [-122.000000, 736.000000, 1.626667]]

loop_verts = [[5 * math.sin(a / 57.3), 5 * math.cos(a / 57.3), 0.0] for a in range(360)]

line = pi3d.Lines(vertices=verts, material=[0.7, 0.7, 0.1], line_width=4, strip=True,
                 x=128, y=-735, z=8.0)
line.set_shader(shader)
loopx = pi3d.Lines(vertices=loop_verts, material=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], strip=True, z=8.0)
loopx.set_shader(shader)
loopy = pi3d.Lines(vertices=loop_verts, material=[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], strip=True, z=8.0, rx=90)
loopy.set_shader(shader)
loopz = pi3d.Lines(vertices=loop_verts, material=[.0, 0.0, 1.0], strip=True, z=8.0, ry=90)
loopz.set_shader(shader)

CAMERA.position((-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)) # NB look at pi3d_demos for examples of using the mouse and keyboard
CAMERA.rotate(-5.0, -5.0, 0.0)    # for camera positioning and closing the program down

while DISPLAY.loop_running():
  line.draw()
  loopx.draw()
  loopy.draw()
  loopz.draw()
```